# Attaching SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database via C#

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, authorization, access-denied, sqlcmd

I am having trouble attaching a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database. I have to do it via a .Net exe.

Here is my code

```
string fileName = @"C:\express\createdb.sql";
ProcessStartInfo psiSqlCmd = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd.exe", @" -S            .\SQLExpress -U sa -o c:\express.out\txt -i """ + @fileName + @""" -P sa123");

psiSqlCmd.UseShellExecute = false;
psiSqlCmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
psiSqlCmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psiSqlCmd.Verb = "runas";
Process sqlCmdProcess = new Process();

sqlCmdProcess.StartInfo = psiSqlCmd;
sqlCmdProcess.Start();
```

Here is the code in `createdb.sql`:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE FishLite 
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Express\FishLite.mdf')
FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

I get an access denied error on `FishLite.mdf` file. If I run command prompt under administrative rights and run the `createdb.sql` it works fine. But I can't make it work when I run it via c# code.

I am launching the process under administrative rights but still its not working.

Comment: Is `c:\express.out\txt` a valid path/filename for output?

Comment: What is the exact error message it gives you?